# Why won't LAN on Minecraft 1.10.2 work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've seen similar questions, but not one specifically for vanilla Minecraft 1.10.2.  My dad and I are on the same LAN, same version and have separate accounts, but the multiplayer world doesn't show up (Open to LAN), Multiplayer...  As far as the computers, they are both Mac Airs with El Capitan.

What are we doing wrong? We have played multiplayer heaps of times on previous versions.

Comment: What have you tried so far in relation to actually connecting to one another? You can try connecting to "localhost" or your actual IP address

Comment: I'm voting to mark this as a duplicate because all troubleshooting steps on the linked page are 100% applicable to this question.

Comment: Thanks guys.  The question that already had an answer helped, as I learned how to use the direct connection option, although how to find my ip address was something I had to look up elsewhere, as the instructions for doing that were for Windows not Mac.